# Pandas How to hide the header when the output need header as a condition to filter the result?

Tags: python, pandas

### **Solution**

If you hide the header of the output. use the header = None option. And notice that just use it when you are going to print it. For the reason that if you set the header = None when you load the data, the name of the column is unusable to you, so you can't use it to filter the data or do something else.

For example :

`print(ResDf.to_string(header = None))`

### **Update**

The output I want has no header. 
For example the output is

```
  0   1  2   3  4   5  6   7  8   9   10 11 <------------------column name
3  b   7  a   4  b   2  b   6  b NaN  10  b
8  a   8  a   6  b   2  c   4  a NaN  10  c
```

The output I want is

------------without column name -------------------

```
3  b   7  a   4  b   2  b   6  b NaN  10  b
8  a   8  a   6  b   2  c   4  a NaN  10  c
```

But it can't be done by using `header = none`, so I wonder how to make it?

Thing is that if you set the `header = None` option, the column name can't be used as a condition to filter the data. Cuz there is no column name already. 
For example I set the filter ( or called *mask*) as `mask = df[u'客户'].str.contains(Client, na=False) & df[u'型号'].str.contains(GoodsType, na=False)`. If you set the header = None I think that there is no `型号` or `客户` in the dataframe, so It can't be used. So how to hide header when you still want to use the header to filter the output data?

I want the pandas output without the **header**, but the output needs the header to filtered.

Here is my code, I knew the trick to set the `header=None`, but I can't do that because the header still is used as a condition to filter the output. For example here I want the output with the **'客户'**(which is a column name) contain the certain word '**Tom**'(For example). If I use the `header = None` option, the '客户' will not be recognized. So how to get the output without the header, in my condition?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: gbk -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import re
import os

import sys

Client    = sys.argv[1]
GoodsType = sys.argv[2]
Weight    = sys.argv[3]

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(script_dir ) # change to the path that you already know

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
# df = pd.read_excel("packagesum.xlsx", header = None) # '客户' will not be recognized when set the header to None
df = pd.read_excel("packagesum.xlsx")
# print(str(df.ix[:,u'客户经理':u'内袋标贴'][df[u'客户'].str.contains(Client, na = False)][df[u'型号'].str.contains(GoodsType, na = False)]))
ResDf = df.ix[:,u'客户经理':u'留样'][df[u'客户'].str.contains(Client, na = False)][df[u'型号'].str.contains(GoodsType, na = False)]
ResDf[u'重量'] = Weight
print(str(ResDf))
with open('GoodsTypeRes.txt', 'w') as the_file:
   the_file.write(str(ResDf))
```

This is the header of my excel file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need parameter `names` for set column names if does not exist, also `header = None` can be omit:

```
#change column names by your data
df = pd.read_excel("packagesum.xlsx", names=['col1','col2','col3', ...])
```

And then code can be simplify by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
mask = df[u'客户'].str.contains(Client, na=False) & df[u'型号'].str.contains(GoodsType, na=False)
ResDf = df.loc[mask,u'客户经理':u'留样']
ResDf[u'重量'] = Weight


ResDf.to_csv('GoodsTypeRes.tx', header=False)
```

---

Another solution is select columns by position with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

```
df = pd.read_excel("packagesum.xlsx", header=None)

#check positions if corrects, python starts from 0 for first position
mask = df.iloc[:, 2].str.contains(Client, na=False) & df.iloc[:, 4].str.contains(GoodsType, na=False)
#all columns
ResDf = df[mask].copy()
#add new column to position 10 what is same as column name
ResDf[10] = Weight


ResDf.to_csv('GoodsTypeRes.tx', header=False)
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(345)
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({0:np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=N),
                   1:np.random.choice([8,7,0], size=N),
                   2:np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=N),
                   3:np.random.randint(10, size=N),
                   4:np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=N),
                   5:np.random.choice([2,0], size=N),
                   6:np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=N),
                   7:np.random.randint(10, size=N),
                   8:np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=N),
                   9:np.random.choice([np.nan,0], size=N),
                   10:np.random.choice([1,0], size=N),
                   11:np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=N)})
print (df)
  0   1  2   3  4   5  6   7  8    9   10 11
0  a   7  b   6  a   2  a   7  c  0.0   1  b
1  a   8  b   3  b   0  a   7  a  NaN   0  b
2  b   8  b   3  b   2  a   8  c  NaN   1  b
3  b   7  a   4  b   2  b   6  b  NaN   0  b
4  c   0  b   2  c   2  c   7  a  NaN   1  b
5  a   0  a   8  c   2  b   1  c  NaN   1  b
6  a   8  b   5  c   2  a   5  a  0.0   0  a
7  b   8  a   2  c   0  a   1  a  NaN   1  c
8  a   8  a   6  b   2  c   4  a  NaN   0  c
9  c   0  b   2  a   0  b   2  c  0.0   0  b
```

---

```
Client = 'a'
GoodsType = 'b'
Weight = 10

mask = df.iloc[:, 2].str.contains(Client, na=False) & df.iloc[:, 4].str.contains(GoodsType, na=False)
ResDf = df[mask].copy()

ResDf[10] = Weight
print (ResDf)
  0   1  2   3  4   5  6   7  8   9   10 11
3  b   7  a   4  b   2  b   6  b NaN  10  b
8  a   8  a   6  b   2  c   4  a NaN  10  c
```

Comment: First of all, really nice code in my option, truely~ But I need the output without header, the `name` option can't make it. The output I get still have the header.
The `names` option must contain all the column name? If I get the error msg like this `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 14 elements, new values have 13 elements`

Comment: Exactly, you need all columns names.

Comment: I use the code you post if the header is `none`, I will get the error msg like this `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. If I don't add the `header = None` option the result I get is `Empty DataFrame`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148212/discussion-between-lee-and-jezrael).

Comment: seems not right yet, I chat with you in the chat room.

Comment: I think the output still get a header, how to remove that header?

Comment: Need parameter `header=False` - `ResDf.to_csv('GoodsTypeRes.tx', header=False)`

Comment: As I said in the post if you use the header = false option, the header can't be used to filter the output.

Comment: Yes, but you use `iloc` solution and then column names are not necessary.

Comment: I know the solution just set the header = None option when you want to print it, will be fine. Really tnx for you help~

Comment: I think if need dataframe write to file without header is necessary `ResDf.to_csv('GoodsTypeRes.tx', header=False)` and then for read this file need `ResDfagain = pd.read_csv('GoodsTypeRes.tx', header=None)`.

Comment: If my answer is helpful dont forget `accept` it. Thanks.